# Thoughts about asp.net mvc 2 preview 1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm interested what you think about [preview 1 release of asp.net mvc2](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/07/31/asp-net-mvc-v2-preview-1-released.aspx) ? Especially about input helpers? Do you think they would do their job better than [Eric Hexter input buliders](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/hex/archive/2009/06/17/opinionated-input-builders-part-8-the-auto-form.aspx) ?f
I'm interested especially in input builders becouse I don't know which to use in my next project and input builders from mvc2 are the only feature important for me

Comment: I'm interested in what you think about making this a community wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was little bit dissapointed - somewhy wanted to see more new&powerful stuff.
But that's just a preview1 - maybe there is no reason to be.

Input builders looks nice, can't say much more. ^^

---

Now i've changed my mind a bit. I just love RenderAction and Templates.

Comment: It's only been what, 4 months?  And the guys were also working on ASP.Net 4.0, so give them a little time.

Comment: I didn't tell anything is wrong. Framework is progressing and that's good. :)

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping to see easier mechanisms for testing fully rendered views so you can

1) Make sure the view actually is rendered without hitting any null reference exceptions or the like
2) Being able to perform xhtml validation on the rendered product

The Areas support could be handy on large scope applications.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of these features are already standard in other MVC frameworks, so I think it's very encouraging to see!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some cool features, many of which are currently provided by 3rd party libraries. The one I can't see the real need for is the new HttpPost attribute. I think I prefer the current mechanism of [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)].

Comment: HttpPost is just a shorthand feature to save keystrokes. They won't be removing AcceptVerbs as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be a natural progression and maturation of a framework.  A lot of these features are already standard in other MVC frameworks, so I think it's very encouraging to see!